# Redirecting to modified URL

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a non-server side website (using only html, css and jquery), and I have found how to modify the url path of a directory:

E.g.
Change mywebsite.com/pageaboutanimals.html to mywebsite.com/page-about-animals using:

```
window.location.href = '/page-about-animals';
```

But is it in some way possible to make it so that I can send someone the link `mywebsite.com/page-about-animals` and it working? I.e. for it to work the other way around too? On a purely non-serverside website.

Answer (score 0):

Without server interaction, the easiest (and it's hardly easy) is to create that subdirectory, i.e. create the folder 'page-about-animals' and place your 'pageaboutanimals.html' file renamed to 'index.html' inside.

If it's non-server side, what are you using to serve the pages? Surely you're using Microsoft IIS or Apache or some server software? Or it's simply a shared folder on a network/intranet?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

So if I create the folder, the url would be mywebsite.com/page-about-animals/index.html ? Or could it be without the index.html part?

It's simply a purely html, css, jquery website hosted on firebase.

In some cases when I use hashes to change url:

```
window.location.hash = 'vid';
```

I can't navigate to these hashes either.

Comment: The URL could be without the index.html part; the server will serve that page as a default for the folder (generally speaking). You could also look at using Rewrites on Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites